# Why it will complain when I want to use Identifiable and add id by UUID()?

Tags: ios

```
struct Todo : Equatable,Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var content :String

    static func ==(lhs: Todo, rhs: Todo) ->  Bool{
        return lhs.content == rhs.content
    }//Equatable Protacol's things
}
```

Comment: What is the "complaint"?

Comment: What's more you don't need to implement `static func ==(lhs: Todo, rhs: Todo)` Compiler will do it for you since all properties conforms to `Equatable `